# Android DOM object to string

Tags: android, xml, dom, domparser

I am basically stuck with my DOM object with the data I want and I'm trying to output that to a string. Here here the code I am using to parse my xml file:

```
public ORGRTools insertUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String password)
{
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom = docBuilder.parse (new File("/mnt/sdcard/Commands.xml"));
        NodeList items = dom.getElementsByTagName("login");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node item = items.item(i);
                    NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node property = properties.item(j);
                        String name = property.getNodeName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("userName")) {
                            property.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(userName);
                        }
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
                            property.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(password);
                        }
                    }
        }
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //invalid character in xml
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this;
}
```

That being said, I have the following function that uses the member variable dom from the previous code above to try to get its string representation:

```
public String serialize()
{
     try
        {
           DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(dom);
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
           TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
           transformer.transform(domSource, result);
           String retVal= writer.toString();
           return retVal;
        }
        catch(TransformerException ex)
        {
                   //exception here but does not print stack trace... weird
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
}
```

However, I get the following exception(see comment). Does anyone have a clue what's going on? Whys is transformation to string failing? I've been stuck in this for a few hours so any help would be good. Any API level is ok.

Thanks!
--Edit--
Here is the structure I am trying to process. Basically, the idea is to have one of these models installed with the .apk and have these models communicate with a server. So I need to fill in the user credential data:

```
<commands>
<login>
    <userName>itemstr</userName>
    <password>itemstr</password>
</login>
<analyse>
    <imageName>itemstr</imageName>
    <imageHeight>itemnum</imageHeight>
    <imageWidth>itemnum</imageWidth>
    <recordID>itemstr</recordID>
</analyse>
<retrieve>
    <record>itemnum</record>
</retrieve>
```

Comment: Did you try to add another `catch block` under yours to catch other exceptions and see if if it prints the stack trace?

Comment: Hi iturki, I added Exception to the catch but the debugger still skipped it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then try this: move the `null return` outside the catch block. I'm not comfortable with returning null. It maybe the cause of the problem. Consider returning an empty String or a user-defined one.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to simple xml framework it will be more easy to work with serializing xml to object.

Here is sample to explain u about its use...

**Serializing a simple object**
In order to serialize an object to XML a series of annotations must be placed within that object. These annotations tell the persister how the object should be serialized. For example take the class shown below. Here there are three different annotations, one used to describe the name of the root element, one that describes an XML message element, and a final annotation for an id attribute.

```
@Root
public class Example {

   @Element
   private String text;

   @Attribute
   private int index;

   public Example() {
      super();
   }  

   public Example(String text, int index) {
      this.text = text;
      this.index = index;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
      return text;
   }

   public int getId() {
      return index;
   }
}
```

To serialize an instance of the above object a Persister is required. The persister object is then given an instance of the annotated object and an output result, which is a file in this example. Other output formats are possible with the persister object.

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
File result = new File("example.xml");

serializer.write(example, result);
```

Hope this answers ur question..

Comment: Siranjeevi, I modified my question to include the data model I'm trying to process. I think I agree with you that I need to use a more simple xml frame work. Do you have good experience with one?